# How to programmatically ignore specific code blocks with rehype-highlight?

Tags: mdxjs, rehypejs

I have some MDX pages that use [rehype-highlight](https://github.com/rehypejs/rehype-highlight) for syntax highlighting. I'd also like to use [Sandpack](https://sandpack.codesandbox.io/) to provide little runnable sandboxes, the way the React docs do ([example](https://react.dev/learn/managing-state#reacting-to-input-with-state), [code](https://github.com/reactjs/react.dev/blob/main/src/content/learn/managing-state.md?plain=1#L29-L108)).

So I need for rehype-highlight to act on standalone code blocks, but not on code blocks that are inside a `<Sandpack>` component.

````
// test.mdx
# Test

```js
const foo = () => {
    console.log('rehype-highlight should apply syntax highlighting here')
}
``` 

<Sandpack>

```js 
const foo = () => {
    console.log('rehype-highlight should not touch this')
}
```

</Sandpack>
````

According to the [rehype-highlight docs](https://github.com/rehypejs/rehype-highlight#example-ignoring), you can add a `no-highlight` class to a `<code>` block to have the highlighter ignore it. So I've tried inserting a little rehype plugin to add `no-highlight` to code blocks that are generated inside a `<Sandbox>` component. The plugin is doing what it's supposed to -- it's applying the class:

[image]

But in spite of the `no-highlight` class, the code block is still getting the highlighter markup applied to it, which gets in the way of my Sandpack component parsing it.

I've made a CodeSandbox repro here:
http://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/sandpack-vs-remark-rehype-rnh3tx

Is there a better way to programmatically get rehype-highlight to ignore code blocks that are inside a `<Sandpack>` component?

1. List item